# Where can I add the FindViewById() and the listeners in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I created a `Fragment` and called it `Kabar` and I can see that the `Button` and the `TextView` appears as expected.

Here is my `Fragment`:

```
public class Kabar extends Fragment   {
    private Button button;
    private TextView text;

    public Kabar() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kabar , container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

This is my `fragment_kabar` layout:

```
 <FrameLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="com.examplee.my.Kabar">

     <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tt1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="mohsen kabar" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/tt2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginTop="113dp"
             android:text="Button"
             android:layout_below="@+id/mohsenkabar"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
             android:layout_marginRight="93dp"
             android:layout_marginEnd="93dp" />
     </RelativeLayout>
```

I need to use the `Button` and the `TextView`.

Where can I place this code?

```
text=(TextView) text.findViewById(R.id.tt1);
button=(Button) button.findViewById(R.id.tt2);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tt1.setText("kkk mmm bbb ddd");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this add this code in your `kabar` fragment

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kabar , container, false);

      TextView  text=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tt1);
      TextView  button=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tt2);

      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
      text.setText("kkk mmm bbb ddd");
       }
   });
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's two options **onCreateView** and **onViewCreated** (preferred) methods.

[void onViewCreated (View view, 
                Bundle savedInstanceState)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle))

> Called immediately after onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup,
>   Bundle) has returned, but before any saved state has been restored in
>   to the view. This gives subclasses a chance to initialize themselves
>   once they know their view hierarchy has been completely created. The
>   fragment's view hierarchy is not however attached to its parent at
>   this point.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with folowing in **onCreateView**

```
text  =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tt1); 
button=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.tt2); 
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        text.setText("kkk mmmm bbbb ddd"); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

make this change in your code

```
text=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tt1);
button=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.tt2);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        text.setText("kkk 'mmm' 'bbb' 'ddd'");
    }
});
```

Comment: if your query answered, correctly don't mind to mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You should Add your code in the `OnCreateView` in your Kabar `Fragment`:

```
public class Kabar extends Fragment {

    private Button button;
    private TextView text;

    public Kabar() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kabar , container, false);

        TextView  text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tt1);
        Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.tt2);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                text.setText("kkk mmm bbb ddd");
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```